# Prenex Form for this type?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to solve a problem of first order logic considering the Prenex Normal Form. Namely, I have to convert this type in Prenex Form and I can't find a solution. Can you please help me?

$$(∀x)A(x) ↔ (∃x)B(x)$$

Comment: Unpack the bi-conditional as a conjunction of conditionals.

Comment: See [here](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~lkari/prenex.pdf)

Comment: I have already seen this (and other documents for the prenex form conversion) but still can't end in a prenex form type. Converting the bicondiotional in conjuction is a step which i had no doubt from the beggining, but after this step it comes a complex type which I can't finally convert in prenex form. Thanks for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Fist step: $(\forall x Ax \land \exists y By) \lor (\lnot \forall z Az \land \lnot \exists u Bu) \equiv (\forall x Ax \land \exists y By) \lor (\exists z \lnot Az \land \forall u \lnot Bu)$

Comment: Second step : $∃y∀x(Ax ∧ By) ∨ ∃z∀u(¬Az ∧ ¬Bu)$. And the same for the third and final step.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't thought of this!